# Не читает подкаталог с файлами

Tags: java

Файлы с главного каталога считывает а с подкаталога нет в чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileLocation = "D:\\music";
    File dir = new File(fileLocation);
    readFiles(dir);

}




 public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){

    try {
        if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {

            for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                    input.close();

                    String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
                    System.out.println("Artists: " + metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                    System.out.println("Album : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                    System.out.println("Duration : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:duration"));
                    System.out.println("Path : " + fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                else{


                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                    input.close();

                    String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
                    System.out.println("Artists: " + metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                    System.out.println("Album : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                    System.out.println("Duration : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:duration"));
                    System.out.println("Path : " + fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                    readFiles(fileloop);

                }

            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все получилось я просто сделал так, вчера когда засыпал пришла мысль в голову)

```
        if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {

            for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                    input.close();

                    String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
                    System.out.println("Artists: " + metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                    System.out.println("Album : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                    System.out.println("Duration : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:duration"));
                    System.out.println("Path : " + fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                else{

                    readFiles(fileloop);

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот это работает как надо,

```html
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileLocation = "D:/music";
        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        readFiles(dir);
    }

    static void readFiles(File baseDirectory) throws Exception {
        for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
            if (fileloop.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("file : " + fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("dir : " + fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                readFiles(fileloop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

а у Вас  `InputStream` в windows не открываются из-за

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

наверное...

Comment: да именно это и было)